# Unmet dependency issue after failed Skype install

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, skype

I'm pretty new to linux/ubuntu so I have no idea what is going on. I tried searching some of the errors I'm having online, and I tend to see similar information that hasn't helped. I figure I should post my actual errors for someone to look at. After running:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
cairo-dock-plug-ins-data compiz-plugins gcc-4.8-base:i386 libaudio2:i386
libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386
libcups2:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
libdrm-radeon1:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libetpan15 libexpat1:i386
libffi6:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgcrypt11:i386
libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-wily:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386
libglapi-mesa-lts-wily:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgnutls26:i386
libgpg-error0:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386
libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libice6:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386
libjpeg8:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeybinder0 libkeyutils1:i386
libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 libllvm3.6:i386 liblzma5:i386
libmysqlclient18:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386
libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-network:i386
libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386
libqt4-webkit:i386 libqt4-xml:i386 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386
libqtdbus4:i386 libqtgui4:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libsm6:i386
libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libtasn1-6:i386
libtiff5:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386
libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386
libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386
libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxml2:i386
libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386
libxv1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 mysql-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
liblzma5:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
liblzma5:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/84.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 324 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 210719 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../liblzma5_5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking liblzma5:i386 (5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/liblzma5_5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2_i386.deb (--unpack):
cannot compute MD5 hash for file '/usr/share/doc/liblzma5/THANKS': failed to read (Input/output error)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Did you recently make changes to your /etc/apt/sources.list? Do you have Synaptic installed? Synaptic sometimes does a good job of identifying and resolving issues like this.